# TVirtualStringTree: What is Column parameter in OnGetText event?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

The OnGetText event procedure definition is:

```
TVSTGetTextEvent = procedure (Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: UnicodeString) of object;
```

The documentation CHM help file for this event just says:

> Use other resources like the news group or the Delphi Gems message
>   board to find a description.

I've seen some other posts on SO where they are checking for (Column < 0) in this event, so I'm curious about what this is?

FWIW, I'm trying to implement a Parent-Child tree view from database data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define columns in the virtual tree's `Header.Columns` collection. The `Column` parameter that is passed to any event method where it's given, is the 0 based index of the column in this collection.

The `Column` parameter value can be either the 0 based index of the processed column, or `NoColumn` (which has internally value -1), which indicates that there is no column in your virtual tree.

Comment: In what case is (Column < 0) ? I'm not using Header.Columns (grid layout), but a proper tree-view layout.

Comment: In case when you have no columns in your virtual tree. But that test is wrong. It should have been `if Column = NoColumn then`. Generally, if you have no columns in your tree, you don't need to test this parameter at all.

Comment: And A Column object's `Position` property is the run-time position of that column, because the user might use drag-and-drop to re-order the columns.